# React: Trigger click on div if two props match

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So I have a component which looks sth. like this:

```
class TestComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  this.state = {}
  }

  render() {
    const {id, neededId, handleOnClick } = this.props
    return (
        <div id="reviews" onClick={handleOnClick}>Click me</div>
    )
  }
}
```

So the use case is that I click on an anchor on the same page (somewhere in a parent component) which will scroll to the `<div />` and the `onClick` should then also be triggered, if the `neededId === id`.

So basically, the `onClick` should be triggered of course if I click the `<div />` OR if I click on some anchor on the page and get scrolled to the `<div />` element. The `neededId` gets mapped to the props via redux and is always available in the props as soon as a user clicks on the anchor.

Just imagine the `<div />` as an accordion which should open if I click on the anchor which will scroll the user to the closed accordion.

How can I achieve this with React? Like, I know the super easy solution with jQuery or something, but that's not wanted obviously! :-D

Thanks!

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. You want the `handleOnClick` to trigger when another component triggers a scroll so that the `TestComponent` comes into view?

Comment: I have an accordion on my page which is rendered in the `TestComponent` and all accordion items are closed by default. If the user clicks on the accordion-item (= `<div />`), the accordion will open.

Same should happen if the user clicks somewhere on the page on an anchor with the id #reviews for example, which will scroll to the `<div id="reviews" />`. The accordion should then be open as well. The opening is handled by the `handleOnClick` fn.